# Waiting for Jquery Get Function to complete

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a google chrome extension and I am facing a problem:

I use Jquery get function to get the source code of a weblink and then search for links within a certain div class in the following way:

```
$.get(link,function(mainImage1){
                    $(mainImage1).find('.inlinepic img').each(function(){
                    imageLink=  $(this).attr('src');    
                    alert(imageLink);           
                });
```

After getting imageLink I would like to update the an image through this way

```
$("#my_image").attr("src",imageLink);
```

But the problem is my code already executes setting the image link before completing the function. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.get`, try using `.ajax` and set the value of the `async` parameter to `false`, and observe `complete` and `success` callbacks.

```
$.ajax( {
  async : false,
  url : 'URL-TO-GET',
  type : 'get',
  dataType : 'json',
  beforeSend : function ( ) { },
  complete : function ( ) { },
  success : function ( data ) { }
} );
```

[.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)